# KineticJS - delete a selected image

Tags: kineticjs

My code is in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dipens/kLnxK/6/)

Looking specifically at:

```
$d('#delete').click(function(){
        var toRemove = imageSelected;
        if(toRemove !== false)
        {
            var groups = layer.get('Group');
            for(var j=0; j < groups.length; j++)
            {
                var gid = groups[j].getId();

                if(gid == toRemove)
                {           
                    groups[toRemove].destroy();
                    imageSelected = false;
                    layer.clear();
                    deselect();             
                    sources[toRemove] = null;
                    j = groups.length;
                }           
            }
        }       
    });
```

What I am trying to do:
1) User should be able to click any image (ie anchors appear) and then the "Delete" link under the canvas. Image should then disappear (I don't need to cache etc it).

2) User should be able to click "Add Monkey" - under the canvas, click any of the images (including the newly added monkey) and delete it.

I think that once I have implemented the above - I should understand the workings of kinetic much better - for now I am baffled!

Many Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, I think it is easier to just use a variable called `selectedNode` and assign that as the actual Kinetic node you are selecting, instead of its `id`.

`selectedGroup = new Kinetic.Shape({name:'emptyNode'});`

```
function select(node) {
  ...
  selectedGroup = node.parent;
  ...
}

function deselect() {
  ...
  selectedGroup = new Kinetic.Shape({name:'emptyNode'});
  ...
}
```

I named the selectedGroup as `name: 'emptyNode'` on init and deselect, so that you can tell when there is no node selected.

Now that you have the Kinetic Object stored in a variable, you can easily call `destroy()` (since you don't want to cache it) on that node.

```
$d(function() {
  $d('#delete').click(function(){
    if (selectedGroup.getName() !== 'emptyNode') {
        selectedGroup.destroy();
        layer.draw();
    }
  });   
});
```

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/69hh4/)

**Note:** We want to destroy the Group because it contains all the anchors and the image.

Oh also, since you declared `var layer;` globally in your application scope, I had to remove the `var` declartion for `layer` inside your `initStage` function. That way `layer` is accessible globally to your Jquery Ready Function.

Comment: You're probably also safe to comment out or remove your selectedImage and selectedImageID code.

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm getting there!